# Where from freeswitch takes caller_id_name

Tags: freeswitch

I have freeswitch installation based on fusionbpx.

I see in cdr there is caller_id_name not specified in freeswitch somehow.

When I create users I specify only phone and password.

How can I find where these caller_id_names come from?

When I use tcpdump

tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -vvv -i eth1 port 5060

I can see only phone numbers, ip addresses but not caller id names.

Answer (score 0):

In Freeswitch this can be defined as a [Channel Variable](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Channel+Variables) in the user directory, dialplan, or pre-defined in `vars.xml`. To find out where it is defined in your setup, you could grep for the value you are seeing in your CDRs for `caller_id_name` like this:

`grep -r "{caller_id_name from CDRs}" /{path to freeswitch}/freeswitch/*`

For example:

`grep -r "John Doe" /usr/local/freeswitch/*`

This should show you where it is defined in your setup.